# Pygame- Frame Per Second

Tags: python, pygame

I watched in the pygame tutorial

And following is [example code](https://github.com/buckyroberts/Source-Code-from-Tutorials/blob/master/Pygame/08_PythonGameDevelopment.py)

and the following is the part of the example

```
lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300
lead_x_change = 0
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        gameExit = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            lead_x_change = -10
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            lead_x_change = 10

    lead_x += lead_x_change
```

i'm not sure how it does work?

my understanding is  that when press K_LEFT

And the lead_x_change = -10

Then out of the event loop

Then lead_x minus 10

And this action called one frame

So if the Frame Per Second = 30

The lead_x minus 30 times so that moved 300 unit per second?

But the display width just be 800

I tested it because it seemed to make sense

Correct?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean, i don't understand the question.

Comment: The event loop executes until the game is over.  I think your indentation must be incorrect.  Shouldn't `lead_x += lead_x_change` be inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. you want to know what does the code do and why it does what it does.

Let's imagine we have a car game that tries to avoid hitting blocks ( which is actually a real game I made built on pygame tutorials on YouTube, here is the Github page if u r interested : https://github.com/m41kdev3lops/RacerZ)

**lead_x** is the X position of your car ( How far left from your screen edge in PIXELS). you want to change the **X position** of your car by **N** ( which is 10 in this case) and that's what your code does! it makes the **lead_x** value change based on **lead_x_change** value. Which actually moves your car left and right based on the **Minus** in the value ( Move left if the value is **Negative** or move right if the value is **Positive**)

### Why does it work ?

Because I don't understand why it shouldn't! if what you mean is it should move **N * Frame rates** then no, it moves only **N pixels**. FPS is just how many frames are actually displayed in second and **lead_x *DOES NOT*** relate to FPS ( It doesn't change the value per frame like you guessed ).

I hope this helps

Comment: thank you very much! This is helpful!!! But if lead_x DOES NOT relate to FPS.Why the FPS = 10 v.s. FPS = 1000,then the  **lead_x** in one second is very different.(which FPS=1000 is very **fast**)

Comment: well, if you display a 1000 frames per second then of course it will be a lot faster than just displaying 10 frames per second. the point here is **lead_x** moves the object by pixels not by fps.

You are welcome :)

Comment: @M41kDev3lops that gigantic **Why does it work ?** is misleading, it doesn't work, because there is wrong indentation on line 6 (it is not increased after `for` on line 5)